# Is dumping to FIFO has more overhead than to /dev/null?

Tags: pipe, fifo, dev-null

I'm trying to solve a simple problem.

I wish to start a long-running program in verbose mode, but I want to trash all of its output by default, and when some misbehavior occurs I wish to *reattach* the output to my terminal.

The program itself is started by a *systemctl* rule.

I thought on various solutions:

1. Starting it as `program > /dev/null` and use some `ptrace` later to change the default output when investigation is needed
2. Starting it as `mkfifo /tmp/mystdout; program > /tmp/mystdout` and later cat the contents of the fifo

However I want to detect which approach is more effective, taking into account that 95% of the output is not needed to keep. (I know outputting to fifo is not keeping the contents!)

So I want to understand *if* (and *how* and *why*) `program > /tmp/mystdout` has worse performance in any aspects than `program > /dev/null`.

Inspecting it with `lsof` both cases looks very identical.

PS: *worse performance*: I'm interested if by-design any of those 2 above has performance drawback(s) against the other.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but wouldn't `time ./your-program > /dev/null` measure fine? You can use git-bash to check on windows. If you're on linux `perf` can benchmark. Remember to build with debug symbols (`-g`)

Comment: A fifo has a buffer of finite size, usually a few KB.  If you send the output to a fifo that nobody is reading, it will accumulate in the buffer at first, but once the buffer is full, further writes will block.  Your `program` will then be stuck waiting for someone to read from the buffer and will not be able to do its usual work (unless it is designed to do the writes asynchronously or in a separate thread).  So they are really not interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

Your second approach doesn't work at all, for reasons unrelated to performance. FIFOs have a finite buffer size, and if you have a program that writes to one without anything reading from it, eventually the buffer will fill up, and then your program will just hang until you attach to it.